# Performance difference while joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to join `Account` AND `Sales` tables.

Primary key of `Account` table : `id,YearCode,AgentId`

Which query **runs faster**

Query #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM account A
     JOIN sales s on a.id = s.id
                     AND a.yearcode = s.yearcode
                     AND a.agentid = s.agentid
WHERE a.yearcode = 1
      AND a.agentid=56
      AND a.id=976
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT *
FROM Account A
     JOIN sales s on a.id=s.id
WHERE s.yearcode=1
      AND s.agentid=56
      AND a.yearcode=1
      AND a.agentid=56
      AND a.id=976
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT *
FROM account a, sales s
WHERE a.id=s.id
      AND a.yearcode=s.yearcode
      AND a.agentid=s.agentid
      AND a.agentid=56
      AND a.yearcode=1
      AND a.id=976
```

Comment: Query #1 is the one that's **most standards-compliant** and thus I would use that one. I don't think you'll see any significant performance differences between the three. But your best option is: **try it yourself and measure!**

Comment: Query #2 as you have it typed out here is **invalid syntax** (`where and ....`)

Comment: OF course `select *` is generally frowned upon as alterations to the table suddenly make your query have different quantity of columns and doesn't deal with name collisions nicely.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I corrected Query #2

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM account A
JOIN sales s on a.id = s.id AND a.yearcode = s.yearcode AND a.agentid = s.agentid
WHERE a.id =976 AND a.yearcode = 1 AND a.agentid=56
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you choose this?

Comment: Its always the best practice to put columns in the where clause in the order the index is created on them.